# How do i pass a link from selected query in a binded dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

**ASPX**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" DataTextField="Description"    
    DataValueField="NID" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**C#**

```
 string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Description, NID, Link from PushNotification", con);
                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Description";
                DropDownList1.DataValueField = "NID";
                DropDownList1.DataSource = rdr;
                DropDownList1.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

When a selected item is click in the dropdownlist it will redirect to the link from the selected query.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you change you SQL query to: (assuming SQL Server)

```
Select Description, NID + '|' + Link NIDLink from PushNotification
```

Then, change `DataValueField` to:

```
DropDownList1.DataValueField = "NIDLink";
```

Finally, in your code:

```
string[] values = DropdownList1.SelectedValue.Split('|');
string nid = values[0];
string link = values[1];
Response.Redirect(link);
```